# Pass Variable From Nested Annotation In Java

Tags: java, annotations

I wonder that can I pass the annotation variable from other annotation variable. Let me explain it with an example:

Main annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
@Example2(value = Example1.other)
public @interface Example1
{
    String[] other() default {};
}
```

Other annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
public @interface Example2
{
    String[] value() default {};
}
```

In Example1 annotation, Can I pass the Example2 -> value from Example1 -> other property?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - no, you can't do it that way. Because the `Example1.other` attribute value must be constant.

---

But you can declare constant value (`final static String constant = "some constant value"`) in your `@Example1` and use it:

```java
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Example2(Example1.constant)
public @interface Example1 {
    String constant = "some constant value";
    String[] value() default "";
}
```

*Note: all variables in annotations are final and static by default*.

---

Also, you could declare your `@Example2` as follows:

```java
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
public @interface Example2 {
    Example1[] value();
}
```

And use `@Example1` annotations as elements of `@Example2`:

```java
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Example2(@Example1({"some value", "some other value"}))
public @interface Example1 {
    String[] value() default "";
}
```